# Using HttpContext in a background task after response has been completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

A user can trigger a long-running job by sending a request to an ASP.NET Core controller. Currently, the controller executes the job and then sends a 200 OK response. The problem is that the client has to wait rather long for the response.

This is why I am currently trying to process the job in a background task. I am using an `IBackgroundTaskQueue` where all jobs are stored and an `IHostedService` that processes the jobs whenever a new one is enqueued. It is similar to the code in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks).

But the job does need access to the database and therefore the user has to authenticate using Active Directory. Hence, I need access to the `HttpContext.User` property in the background task. Unfortunately, the `HttpContext` is disposed when the response is sent and before the processing of the job begins.

### Demonstration

```cs
public class Job
{
    public Job(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; }
}
```

The controller enqueues a new job in the task queue.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EnqueueJob()
{
    var job = new Job("Hello World");
    this.taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(job);
    return Accepted();
}
```

```cs
public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Job> jobs = new ConcurrentQueue<Job>();
    private SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Job job)
    {
        jobs.Enqueue(job);
        signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task<Job> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        jobs.TryDequeue(out var job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

The `IHostedService` creates a new `JobRunner` for each job it dequeues. I'm using a `IServiceScopeFactory` here to have dependency injection available. `JobRunner` also has a lot more dependencies in the real code.

```cs
public class JobRunnerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue;

    public JobRunnerService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue)
    {
        this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            var job = await taskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var runner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<JobRunner>();
                runner.Run(job);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class JobRunner
{
    private readonly ILogger<JobRunner> logger;
    private readonly IIdentityProvider identityProvider;

    public JobRunner(ILogger<JobRunner> logger, IIdentityProvider identityProvider)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.identityProvider= identityProvider;
    }

    public void Run(Job job)
    {
        var principal = identityProvider.GetUserName();
        logger.LogInformation($"{principal} started a new job. Message: {job.Message}");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class IdentityProvider : IIdentityProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public IdentityProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetUserName()
        => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; // throws NullReferenceException
}
```

Now, when sending a request, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown in `JobRunner.Run()` because `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is null.

### What I've tried

I haven't had a good idea yet how to approach this problem. I know that it would be possible to copy the necessary information from the `HttpContext`, but don't know how to make them available to dependency injection services.

I thought that maybe I could create a new `IServiceProvider` that uses the services of an old one, but replaces the implementation for `IHttpContextAccesor`, but it does not seem to be possible.

---

**How can I use the `HttpContext` in the background task although the response has been completed?**

Comment: `How can I use the HttpContext in the background task although the response has been completed?` Short answer - you can't. Copy the data you need out of `User` before the request ends (into a new object). Then use that new object.

Comment: You've omitted the very section of code (the task queue implementation) which needs to be worked on to provide the solution.

Comment: @jscarle All right, I've added the code for BackgroundTaskQueue.

Comment: That's what I thought. You need to a property to your Job class to hold HttpContext, then pass it when you call QueueBackgroundWorkItem from your controller.

Comment: Alternatively, the same concept, but pass along only the User if you don't need the full HttpContext object.

Comment: @jscarle It did seem like I'm using the HttpContext directly in the JobRunner.Run method. But the IHttpContextAccessor is used deeper in the dependency graph. I've adjusted my sample and added IdentityProvider to demonstrate this. And I don't know how to pass the HttpContext to the IdentityProvider when using dependency injection.

Comment: `I don't know how to pass the HttpContext to the IdentityProvider` - this is the impossible part. Just think about your scopes: `HttpContext` **does not exist** once the request is completed, so there's *no way* to make that work. You'll have to make your own "user accessor" or pass the user explicitly.

Comment: @StephenCleary I like the idea of the user accessor and will try this out. Thank you.

Comment: @Flogex I prefer passing explicitly; once you start defining "ambient data", dependencies get hard to track. That said, one possible implementation of a user accessor would be to use `AsyncLocal<User>` and set it from `IHttpContextAccessor` in the pipeline before actions are invoked.

Comment: And I almost forgot to say: please don't do this at all. Since you're hosting in ASP.NET, there is always the possibility of "losing" background work without being able to notify the user or write to a log. I'd strongly recommend using a reliable (persistent) queue.